# Laravel - Testing what happens after a redirect

Tags: php, redirect, laravel, phpunit

I have a controller that after submitting a email, performs a redirect to the home, like this:

```
return Redirect::route('home')->with("message", "Ok!");
```

I am writing the tests for it, and I am not sure how to make phpunit to follow the redirect, to test the success message:

```
public function testMessageSucceeds() {
    $crawler = $this->client->request('POST', '/contact', ['email' => 'test@test.com', 'message' => "lorem ipsum"]);

    $this->assertResponseStatus(302);
    $this->assertRedirectedToRoute('home');

    $message = $crawler->filter('.success-message');

    // Here it fails
    $this->assertCount(1, $message);
}
```

If I substitute the code on the controller for this, and I remove the first 2 asserts, it works

```
Session::flash('message', 'Ok!');
return $this->makeView('staticPages.home');
```

But I would like to use the `Redirect::route`. Is there a way to make PHPUnit to follow the redirect?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can get PHPUnit to follow redirects with:

**Modern Laravel** (>= 5.5.19):

```
$this->followingRedirects();
```

**Older Laravel** (< 5.4.12):

```
$this->followRedirects();
```

**Usage:**

```
$response = $this->followingRedirects()
    ->post('/login', ['email' => 'john@example.com'])
    ->assertStatus(200);
```

**Note:** This needs to be set explicitly for **each request**.

---

**For versions between these two**:

See https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18016#issuecomment-322401713 for a workaround.

Answer (score 12):

**Laravel 8 tested**

```
$response = $this->post'/contact', ['email' => 'test@test.com', 'message' => "lorem ipsum"]);

$response->assertStatus(302);
$response->assertRedirect('home');

$this->followRedirects($response)->assertSee('.success-message');
//or
$this->followRedirects($response)->assertSee('Ok!');
```

Worked for me, hoped it helps.

Comment: This is really useful for when you want to both test a redirect happened, and verify what you see on the redirected page.  Would be nice to have a `assertRedirectAndFollow()` method so you can continue chaining.

Comment: followsRedirects method not found

Comment: No the correct function is "$this->followRedirects()"

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer

Answer (score 8):

You can tell crawler to follow a redirect this way:

```
$crawler = $this->client->followRedirect();
```

so in your case that would be something like:

```
public function testMessageSucceeds() {
    $this->client->request('POST', '/contact', ['email' => 'test@test.com', 'message' => "lorem ipsum"]);

    $this->assertResponseStatus(302);
    $this->assertRedirectedToRoute('home');

    $crawler = $this->client->followRedirect();

    $message = $crawler->filter('.success-message');

    $this->assertCount(1, $message);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Laravel 5.5 to test redirect you can use [assertRedirect](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/http-tests#assert-redirect):

```
/** @test */
public function store_creates_claim()
{
    $response = $this->post(route('claims.store'), [
        'first_name' => 'Joe',
    ]);

    $response->assertRedirect(route('claims.index'));
}
```

Comment: This has been available since 5.5

Answer (score 0):

```php
//routes/web.php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect()->route('users.index');
})->name('index');


//on my TestClass
$response = $this->get('/');


$response->assertStatus(302);
$response->assertRedirect(route('users.index'));
```

Answer (score -4):

For Laravel 5.6, you can set

```
$protected followRedirects = true;
```

within your class file for your test case

Comment: From what I can tell, at least in Laravel 5.8, is that this will not work if you have more than one test because once the redirect is followed it will reset followRedirects back to false.