# PHPUnit: testing POST request

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I want to to testieng POST request. My controller's method look like this:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
      $this->Validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|string|min:5'
      ]);
      $product = Product::create([
        'name' => $request->name
      ]);
      return redirect()->back();
  }
```

So, I wrote this simple test but I have an error becouse it received 302 code:

```
$response = $this->post('/product/store', [
          'name' => 'Hello'
        ])
        ->assertStatus(201);
```

I think that problem is becouse I redirect page after store data. How I can testing this POST request?

Comment: assert the correct status

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - Testing what happens after a redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27282519/laravel-testing-what-happens-after-a-redirect)

Answer (score 1):

For redirects you can assert a status of 302 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection)

```
$response = $this->post('/product/store', [
      'name' => 'Hello'
    ])
    ->assertStatus(302);
```